# Adding an interactive map to my website

Tags: javascript, dictionary, location, interactive

I'm relatively new coder and am currently putting together a website as part of my University work. I'd really appreciate it someone could give me advice on how I would go about adding an interactive map that uses JavaScript to show my location.

Thanks!

Comment: You can start with checking googlemaps API.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Google maps, just copy paste and edit the latlong to your desired position.

And here is one example getting position from browser and marks it on the map:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation